# load reports with oracle form

Tags: forms, oracle11g, report

I make a form in Oracle form builder 11g 
this form has a button I want to show a report when pressed on this button
I created a report 1.rpt and add it to the form with name REPORT6 
then make this pl/sql code when the button pressed

```sql
declare
  report_id Report_Object;
  ReportServerJob VARCHAR2(100);
  vc_rep_status VARCHAR2(100);
  vjob_id VARCHAR2(100);
  repsvr varchar2(21) := 'RptSvr';
BEGIN 
  report_id:= find_report_object('REPORT6');

  SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id,REPORT_COMM_MODE,SYNCHRONOUS);
  SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id,REPORT_DESTYPE,file);
  SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id,REPORT_DESNAME,'rpout1.html');
  SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id,REPORT_DESFORMAT,'HTMLCSS');
  SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id,REPORT_SERVER,RepSvr);

  ReportServerJob:=run_report_object(report_id);

  vjob_id := substr(reportserverjob,length(repsvr)+2);
  vc_rep_status := REPORT_OBJECT_STATUS(ReportServerJob);

  WHILE vc_rep_status in ('RUNNING','OPENING_REPORT','ENQUEUED', null)
  LOOP
    vc_rep_status:=REPORT_OBJECT_STATUS(ReportServerJob);
  END LOOP;

  IF vc_rep_status='FINISHED' THEN
    WEB.SHOW_DOCUMENT('/reports/rwservlet/getjobid'|| vjob_id ||'?server='||RepSvr,'_blank');
  ELSE
    message ('Report failed with error message '|| vc_rep_status);
  END IF;
END;
```

when I tried this there is an error occurs FRM-14213 can not connect to report server

I tried more solutions as in cmd 
     repserver server=RepSvr batch=yes 
but nothing happen and the error still happened 
I had oracle form and report 11g set up for developement

how can I solve this problem now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution you must choose for deployment and add form and report builder during installing the oracle form and report builder